# Angular version of PHP code snippet

Tags: php, angularjs

```
<li <?php if ($section == "dashboard" || !isset($section) ): ?>class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
    <a href="/dashboard">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw"></i>
        Dashboard
    </a>
</li>
```

I'm rewriting a PHP app using nodejs and angularjs
The above line marks the element as active depending on the current section.
I've been looking for possible ways of doing this with angular without success.

I've tried using a variable on the rootscope to track the current page and use `ng-if` to add a class, or even perhaps `ng-class`

However, I don't want to go that route. I'd be glad to get tips and solutions.
Thanks

Comment: Why didn't use a ng-class ? It the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Yes, `ng-class="{active: !section || section === 'dashboard'}"` is the right solution, as long as you have `section` in the current scope.